# How to get all labels with count by?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, grafana-alerts

I have a set of metrics:

```
metric1{test_title="Title 1", state="passed", report_url="https://"}
metric2{test_title="Title 2", state="failed", report_url="https://"}
metric3{test_title="Title 3", state="failed", report_url="https://"}
metric4{test_title="Title 4", state="passed", report_url="https://"}
```

I want to collect data and send an alert if the particular test fails more than 2 times in a row within 90 minutes and include `report_url` in the alert message.

I've tried:

```
count by (test_title, report_url) 
    (count_over_time(
        {__name__=~"metric(.*)", state="failed"}[90m]
    )
) > 2
```

In this case, I receive the following result if test fails more than 2 times within 90m:

```
{test_title="Title 2", state="failed", report_url="https://"}
{test_title="Title 2", state="failed", report_url="https://"}
{test_title="Title 2", state="failed", report_url="https://"}
```

The goal is to receive just one record with the latest `report_url`:

```
{test_title="Title 2", state="failed", report_url="https://"}
```

But since the `report_url` is unique within the vector I haven't received the desired effect. If I remove `report_url` from the query the timeline builts correctly but in this case, the `report_url` is not added to labels and I don't know how to pass this URL to alert.

Can somebody advise some solution for this?  Thank you in advance.